# What is the pythonic way to implement a parse tree for custom format?

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

I have a project that has a non-standard file format something like:

```
var foo = 5
load 'filename.txt'
var bar = 6
list baz = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

And I want to parse this into a data structure much like BeautifulSoup does.  But this format isn't supported by BeautifulSoup.  What is the pythonic way to build a parse tree so that I can modify the values and re-write it out?  In the end I would like to do something like:

```
data = parse_file('file.txt')
data.foo = data.foo * 2
data.write_file('file_new.txt')
```

Comment: have you tried `shlex` module?

Comment: @JBernardo: `shlex` is only the lexer, though. This looks like a language requiring a parser

Comment: @EliBendersky looks like he has a bunch of commands on each line. The things requiring a parser (last element) looks like valid python code, otherwise it wouldn't make sense. So, even regex + `ast.literal_eval` may solve the problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a solution using pyparsing... it works in your case. Beware that i'm not an expert therefore depending on your standards the code could be ugly... cheers

```
class ConfigFile (dict):
    """
    Configuration file data
    """

    def __init__ (self, filename):
        """
        Parses config file.
        """

        from pyparsing import Suppress, Word, alphas, alphanums, nums, \
            delimitedList, restOfLine, printables, ZeroOrMore, Group, \
            Combine

        equal = Suppress ("=")
        lbrack = Suppress ("[")
        rbrack = Suppress ("]")
        delim = Suppress ("'")

        string = Word (printables, excludeChars = "'")
        identifier = Word (alphas, alphanums + '_')

        integer = Word (nums).setParseAction (lambda t: int (t[0]))
        real = Combine( Word(nums) + '.' + Word(nums) ).setParseAction (lambda t: float(t[0]))
        value = real | integer

        var_kwd = Suppress ("var")        
        load_kwd = Suppress ("load")
        list_kwd = Suppress ("list")            

        var_stm = Group (var_kwd + identifier + equal + value +
                         restOfLine.suppress ()).setParseAction (
                             lambda tok: tok[0].insert(len(tok[0]), 0))

        load_stm = Group (load_kwd + delim + string + delim +
                          restOfLine.suppress ()).setParseAction (
                              lambda tok: tok[0].insert(len(tok[0]), 1))

        list_stm = Group (list_kwd + identifier + equal + lbrack +
                          Group ( delimitedList (value, ",") ) +
                          rbrack + restOfLine.suppress ()).setParseAction (
                              lambda tok: tok[0].insert(len(tok[0]), 2))


        cnf_file = ZeroOrMore (var_stm | load_stm | list_stm)

        lines = cnf_file.parseFile (filename)
        self._lines = []
        for line in lines:
            self._lines.append ((line[-1], line[0]))
            if line[-1] != 1: dict.__setitem__(self, line[0], line[1])            
        self.__initialized = True
        # after initialisation, setting attributes is the same as setting an item

    def __getattr__ (self, key):
        try:
            return dict.__getitem__ (self, key)
        except KeyError:
            return None


    def __setattr__ (self, key, value):
        """Maps attributes to values. Only if we are initialised"""

        # this test allows attributes to be set in the __init__ method
        if not self.__dict__.has_key ('_ConfigFile__initialized'):
            return dict.__setattr__(self, key, value)

        # any normal attributes are handled normally
        elif self.__dict__.has_key (key): 
            dict.__setattr__(self, key, value)

        # takes care of including new 'load' statements
        elif key == 'load':
            if not isinstance (value, str):
                raise ValueError, "Invalid data type"
            self._lines.append ((1, value))

        # this is called when setting new attributes after __init__
        else:
            if not isinstance (value, int) and \
                not isinstance (value, float) and \
                not isinstance (value, list):
                raise ValueError, "Invalid data type"

            if dict.has_key (self, key):
                if type(dict.__getitem__(self, key)) != type (value):
                    raise ValueError, "Cannot modify data type."
            elif not isinstance (value, list): self._lines.append ((0, key))
            else: self._lines.append ((2, key))            
            dict.__setitem__(self, key, value)


    def Write (self, filename):
        """
        Write config file.
        """
        fid = open (filename, 'w')
        for d in self._lines:
            if d[0] == 0: fid.write ("var %s = %s\n" % (d[1], str(dict.__getitem__(self, d[1]))))
            elif d[0] == 1: fid.write ("file '%s'\n" % (d[1]))
            else: fid.write ("list %s = %s\n" % (d[1], str(dict.__getitem__(self, d[1]))))


if __name__ == "__main__":

    input="""var foo = 5
load 'filename.txt'
var bar = 6
list baz = [1, 2, 3, 4]"""

    file ("test.txt", 'w').write (input)
    config = ConfigFile ("test.txt")
    # Modify existent items
    config.foo = config.foo * 2
    # Add new items
    config.foo2 = [4,5,6,7]
    config.foo3 = 12.3456
    config.load = 'filenameX.txt'
    config.load = 'filenameXX.txt'
    config.Write ("test_new.txt")
```

## EDIT

I have modified the class to use

```
__getitem__, __setitem__
```

methods to mimic the 'access to member' syntax to parsed items as required by our poster. Enjoy!

## PS

Overloading of the

```
__setitem__
```

method should be done with care to avoid interferences between setting of 'normal' attributes (class members) and the parsed items (that are accesses like attributes). The code is now fixed to avoid these problems. See the following reference  http://code.activestate.com/recipes/389916/ for more info. It was funny to discover this!

Comment: This looks very good.  I'll give it a try.  The other option that I see is Lepl.  Lepl seems to have better documentation but your example is very nice.  Thanks for providing this.

Comment: never heard about LEPL, but yes I agree that the documentation of pyparsing could be vastly improved. OTOH, using pyparsing is so intuitive that you only need understanding a few examples to get productive. Anyway, the syntax of this LEPL is very similar to pyparsing.

Comment: @CnrAltCanc This is very nice work.  Thought others might jump in with alternatives but this seems very nice and easy to work with which what I was looking for.  Thanks again.

Comment: @dailyglen No worries, glen! I think, unless there are efficiency reasons (read: **huge** input files) invalidating the approach, this code should do its job. If this is not the case, you should switch to a more efficient parsing framework (or even use a compiled language), but even then you can adapt the micro-grammar. Good work!

Comment: what is difference between `Suppress` and `Literal`?

Answer (score 1):

What you have is a custom language you need to parse.

Use one of the many existing parsing libraries for Python. I personally recommend [PLY](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/). Alternatively, [Pyparsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/) is also good and widely used & supported.

If your language is relatively simple, you can also implement a hand-written parser. [Here is an example](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2009/03/20/a-recursive-descent-parser-with-an-infix-expression-evaluator/)

Comment: +1 for PLY. I've build parsers for a few different formats in PLY and it's painless and easy to understand.